# Computing the sentiment score of a sentence

Tags: python

I wrote a script to compute the polarity of sentences. The script is based on this:

> The lexicon based approach assigns a sentiment tags to words in a text based on dictionaries of positive and negative words. A sentiment score is then calculated for each document as:
>
> $$\frac{\text{number of positive words} - \text{number of negative words}}{\text{total number of words}}$$

Is the code below okay? Should I have to improve it to take into consideration the position of the word in the sentence?

```
fileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__file__'))

lexiconpos = open(os.path.join(fileDir, 'Ressources/positive.txt'), 'r', encoding='utf-8')
lexiconpos = set([line.rstrip() for line in lexiconpos])
lexiconneg = open(os.path.join(fileDir, 'Ressources/negative.txt'),'r', encoding='utf-8')
lexiconneg = set([line.rstrip() for line in lexiconneg])

path = os.path.join(fileDir, 'data/reference/freins.tsv')
with open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as l_1:
    next(l_1)
    l_1 = [line.rstrip() for line in l_1]

tagger = treetaggerwrapper.TreeTagger(TAGLANG='fr')     
def process_text(text):
    '''extract lemma and lowerize then removing stopwords.'''

    text_preprocess =[]
    text_without_stopwords= []

    text = tagger.tag_text(text)
    for word in text:
        parts = word.split('\t')
        try:
            if parts[2] == '':
                text_preprocess.append(parts[0])
            else:
                text_preprocess.append(parts[2])
        except:
            print(parts)
            
            
    text_without_stopwords= [word.lower() for word in text_preprocess if word.isalnum()] #if word not in stopWords
    #return text_without_stopwords
    return text_preprocess
 

def extract_info(texte, lexique1, lexique2):

    lemme_treetagger = []
    lemme_sent = []
    len_sent = []
    for elt in texte:
        texte_treetagger = process_text(elt.lower())
        lemme_treetagger.append(" ".join(texte_treetagger))
        len_sent.append(len(" ".join(texte_treetagger)))
        
    word_pos=[]
    word_neg=[]
    word_pos_len=[]
    word_neg_len=[]
    for elt in lemme_treetagger:
        word_pos.append([word for word in lexique1 if word in elt])
        word_neg.append([word for word in lexique2 if word in elt])
    
    for lst in word_pos:
        word_pos_len.append(len(lst))
    for lst in word_neg:
        word_neg_len.append(len(lst))
    
    
    print(len_sent)
    return texte, lemme_treetagger, len_sent, word_pos, word_neg, word_pos_len, word_neg_len

texte, lemme_treetagger, len_sent, word_pos, word_neg, word_pos_len, word_neg_len = extract_info(l_1, lexiconpos, lexiconneg)



def polarity_word(texte, *args):
    
    texte, lemme_treetagger, len_sent, word_pos, word_neg, word_pos_len, word_neg_len = extract_info(texte, lexiconpos, lexiconneg)
    
    for elt in lemme_treetagger:
        print(elt)
        sub_list = list(map(operator.sub, word_pos_len, word_neg_len))
        score = list(map(truediv, sub_list, len_sent))
    
    return score
```

Answer (score 1):

### TSV parsing

You should not need to do this yourself. The [csv](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/csv.html) module accepts a [delimiter](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.delimiter) that you can set to `'\t'`.

### Context management

You use `with` in one out of three file opens - the other two would benefit.

### Inner list

This:

```
set([line.rstrip() for line in lexiconpos])
```

can be

```
{line.rstrip() for line in lexiconpos}
```

The set literal and removal of the inner list will both express this better.